# Wordpress 4.2.4 Twenty fourteen menu button changing

Tags: android, css, wordpress

People say to me that they somehow cannot find menu on my website when browsing on mobile devices. I use Twenty fourteen theme - of course there is a menu button, but people aren't so clever, or it's simple not intuitive. I would like to change the mobile menu button from "=" icon to simple "menu" text. Sorry for my english, polish native. Thanks in advance!

PS. I added in custom-css section something like that:  .menu-toggle:before   { content: "MENU"; }   it changes the icon but if You look on my website www.bdk.brodnica.net using mobile browser there's still some problem with align or box size, tried to add width: parameter, but still don't work

Comment: what you tried ? where is your code ?

Comment: show your site link plz.

Comment: Edited post with some new info

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when I finally got it i think it was simple, but it took me couple hours to find how to do that. Try add following code:

```
.menu-toggle:before {
    color: #fff;
    content: "MENU";
    padding: 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px;
}
```